# How to pattern match on Scala's parser combinator result

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

We have a multithreaded RPC server that parses input strings.  We've run into an issue where Scala's parser combinator library is not multithreaded safe: the var lastNoSuccess in [Parsers.scala](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala) is used by any parsing.  We get a NullPointerException in this line

```
if (!(lastNoSuccess != null && next.pos < lastNoSuccess.next.pos))
```

The default way to implement the parser by making an object that extends one of the Parsers, but I want to construct a parser on demand so each has its own internal state, so I'm using a class instead of an object.  However, I can't get it to compile since I need to pattern match on the result:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

class SqlParserImpl
  extends RegexParsers
{
  val term: Parser[String] = """(?i)term\b""".r
}

object Test
{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    val parser = new SqlParserImpl
    parser.parseAll(parser.term, "term") match {
      // How do I match?
      case SqlParserImpl#Success(result, _) => true
      case SqlParserImpl#NoSuccess => false
    }
  }
}
```

Fails with

```
t.scala:16: error: '=>' expected but '#' found.
          case SqlParserImpl#Success(result, _) => true
                            ^
t.scala:17: error: '=>' expected but '#' found.
          case SqlParserImpl#NoSuccess => false
                            ^
two errors found
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
val parser = new SqlParserImpl
parser.parseAll(parser.term, "term") match {
  case parser.Success(result, _) => true
  case parser.NoSuccess(_, _) => false
}
```

The `#` sign is used to designate a type member. In your case it's using a constructor or an extractor pattern which needs to reference to an object or something that looks like a constructor.

Hmm. I don't have a 2.7 handy. Try this:

```
parser.parseAll(parser.term, "term") match {
  case parser.Success(result, _) => true
  case parser.Failure(_, _) => false
  case parser.Error(_, _) => false
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using Scala 2.7.7 still (yes, we've been too busy to upgrade) and I'm getting this error:

    y.scala:17: error: value NoSuccess is not a member of SqlParserImpl
              case parser.NoSuccess(_, _) => false

Answer (score 4):

I was able to compile the following:

```
object Test {  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val parser = new SqlParserImpl

    println(parser.parseAll(parser.term, "term") match {
      case x: parser.Success[_] => true
      case x: parser.NoSuccess => false
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `NoSuccess` object (with extractor) was added back in 2009, at a time when no code was being backported to 2.7 anymore It's implementation, however, is pretty simple:

```
object NoSuccess {
  def unapply[T](x: ParseResult[T]) = x match {
    case Failure(msg, next)   => Some(msg, next)
    case Error(msg, next)     => Some(msg, next)
    case _                    => None
  }
}
```

So you can replace the `parser.NoSuccess(_, _)` match with one `parser.Failure(_, _)` and one `parser.Error(_, _)` match. But if you are not interested in *what* is being returned, then it's simpler to match against the type:

```
case _: parser.Success[_] => true
case _: parser.NoSuccess  => false
```

Like [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906433/how-to-pattern-match-on-scalas-parser-combinator-result/5906523#5906523) by [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3827/eugene-yokota).